# Como encontrar o número de uma linha específica através de uma função

Tags: javascript, funções, git, indexof

Olá, implementei essa função que busca por um termo em um arquivo txt na IDE do VSCode e retorna o index onde o termo aparece, entretanto eu não quero o index, quero o número específico da linha em que o termo aparece. Não sei se existe algum mecanismo no JavaScript que já faz isso. Nas minhas pesquisas encontrei o  `indexOF`  e o `lastIndexOf`, mas essas funções retornam literalmente um index no texto. Alguém sabe como posso conseguir o número da linha?

```js
var fs = require('fs');

function findLine(file, term) {
    var content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    if (content.includes(term)) {
        return content.lastIndexOf(term);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

OBS.: Preciso implementar essa função para um problema que envolve o `git blame`. Essa função do git retorna quem implementou, quando implementou e o que implementou em uma linha específica de código. Usando o parâmetro `-L`, eu posso escolher a linha em que quero saber quem fez a implementação e por isso estou tentando retornar isso a partir dessa função descrita acima.

Answer (score 2):

- Crie um laço;
- Guarde a próxima ocorrência de quebra de linha (`\n`);
- Verifique se o índice da palavra procurada esta entre a última ocorrência e a próxima de quebra de linha (ou fim do texto).

```js
const buscar = (conteudo, palavra) => {
  const indice = conteudo.indexOf(palavra);
  let deslocamento = 0;
  let linha = 1;
  
  // Para se a palavra não for encontrada
  if (indice === -1) return;

  do {
    const inicio = deslocamento;
    deslocamento = conteudo.indexOf('\n', deslocamento + 1);
    
    // Verifica se não está na última linha
    const fim = deslocamento !== -1 ? deslocamento : conteudo.length;

    // Retorna a linha caso a palavra esteja entre a última ocorrência de quebra de linha e a próxima ou fim
    if (indice >= inicio && indice < fim) {
      return linha;
    }
    
    linha += 1;
  } while(deslocamento !== -1);
};

// Utilização:

const conteudo = `aqui um texto
  onde a palavra chave
  deve ser buscada`;

console.log('linha da palavra "aqui":', buscar(conteudo, 'aqui'));
console.log('linha da palavra "palavra":', buscar(conteudo, 'palavra'));
console.log('linha da palavra "deve":', buscar(conteudo, 'deve'));
console.log('linha da palavra "buscada":', buscar(conteudo, 'buscada'));
console.log('linha da palavra "inexistente":', buscar(conteudo, 'inexistente'));
```

Note que usei na sugestão o segundo parâmetro da função `indexOf` que determina a partir de qual carácter a ocorrência sera verificada.

---

> [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
>
> O método `indexOf()` retorna o índice da primeira ocorrência do valor especificado em searchValue dentro do objeto `String` para o qual foi chamado, começando a busca a partir de `fromIndex`. Retorna -1 se o valor não for encontrado.
>
> [**Sintaxe**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Syntax)
>
> ```
> str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
> ```
>
> ***searchValue***
>
> Uma string representando o valor a ser buscado.
>
> ***fromIndex***
>
> A posição da string original a partir da qual a busca deve começar. Pode ser qualquer número inteiro. O valor padrão é 0. Se `fromIndex < 0` a string toda é percorrida (equivalente a passar 0). Se `fromIndex >= str.length`, o método irá retornar -1.

Answer (score 2):

Arquivos pequenos podem ser fáceis de ler, mas se o arquivo for grande você poderá experimentar uso excessivos de memória, então provavelmente seria melhor ler *linha por linha* e buscar o termo que deseja, e com uma variável incrementando você irá saber qual linha está.

Para resolver isso você pode usar [`readline.createInterface`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readlinecreateinterfaceoptions) e com o evento [`.on('line', callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#event-line) você irá obter linha por linha, exemplo:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const events = require('events');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = 'arquivo.txt';
const search = 'foo';

const input = fs.createReadStream(file);
const interface = readline.createInterface({ input, crlfDelay: Infinity });

let currentLine = 0;

interface.on('line', (line) => {
  currentLine++;

  if (line.indexOf(search) !== -1) {
    console.log(`Linha: ${currentLine}', 'Conteúdo: ${line}`);
    interface.close(); // Fecha a interface
  }
}).on('close', () => {
  console.log(`finish ${currentLine}`);
});
```

Note que as constantes possuem os valores que deseja buscar:

```
const file = 'arquivo.txt'; // Arquivo que deseja fazer a busca
const search = 'foo'; // Termo a ser buscado
```

Você pode usar `for await` com `readline` (desde o Node.js 11) para resolver de forma *linear*:

```
const input = fs.createReadStream(file);
const interface = readline.createInterface({ input, crlfDelay: Infinity });

let currentLine = 0;

for await (const line of interface) {
  currentLine++;

  if (line.indexOf(search) !== -1) {
    console.log(`Linha: ${currentLine}', 'Conteúdo: ${line}`);
    interface.close();
    break; // Interrompe o loop
  }
}
```

Para versões mais antigas do Node.js você pode criar um `Promise` próprio para resolver.

Comment: Otima solucao! +1